# Corrupt pdf downloading when i am using MPDF with ajax call in codeigniter.I am using mPDF library

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, mpdf

code at controller side is given below

```
try {
$this->load->library('m_pdf'); 
$querytype = "advance_search";
$showdata = [];
$pdfFilePath =  utf8_decode("download_pdf.pdf");
ob_start();
$body= $this->load->view('result/pdf_generation', $this->common_advance_search($querytype),false); //here i am loading view for pdf
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($body); 
$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output(FCPATH.$pdfFilePath,'F');// till here i can see the data in view
$result = ob_get_clean();
$response =  array(
        'op' => 'ok',
        'file' => "data:application/pdf;base64,".base64_encode($result)
    );

die(json_encode($response));
}
catch(\Mpdf\MpdfException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

---

### Ajax Code

```
   $.ajax({
url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+scr,
method:"POST",
data:formData,
contentType: false,
cache: false,
processData:false,
dataType:'json'
}).done(function(data){ // here i am able to download the pdf in the browser
    var $a = $("<a>");
    $a.attr("href",data.file);
    $("body").append($a);
    $a.attr("download","file."+ext);
    $a[0].click();
    $a.remove();
});
```

### result is given below

[check result (screen shot added here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwxJD.png)

with this code, it is giving me a currpted PDF file, i am able to get data  and 'Export as pdf'. I have checked whether it is passing data from view, and yes it is doing so. But don't know what is the matter . I is printing everything outside it is working fine, Can anyone please let me know what should I do?

Comment: what is this `ext` variable on your ajax sources contains?

Comment: ext contains pdf as value

Comment: ext contains pdf as value for pdf extension